# How to round a value up WITH ndigits

Tags: python

The built-in function `round()` will round a value down but I want to know how to round a value up.
i know that this is possible with `math.ceil()` but the thing is that `round()` has the keyword argument "ndigits" and `math.ceil()` doesn't. so for example:

```py
>>> round(1024, ndigits=-3)
1000
```

but i want 1100.
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import math

def round(number, n):
    return math.ceil(number * math.pow(10, n+1))*(math.pow(10,-(n+1)))
    
print(round(1024, -3))

# 1100.0
```

A simple function like this would suffice, multiply by `10^(n+1)`, find the ceiling of that number, then multiply by `10^-n-1` (equivalent to dividing by `10^n+1`).